# How to add custom styles to input type="range"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 custom input[type="range"] on my page. I used some JS and CSS to add styles, but it seems that only the first one works properly. What am I doing wrong and how to make all of them act like the first one? I don't want it to be like a regular range and I thought that JS + CSS trick will be the best option. Nevertheless, if you know the way to make it work, I'll be glad to try it.

Here's the link to codepen: https://codepen.io/tomavl/pen/bGabZvj

```js
var fillColor = "#9D3C3C",
  emptyColor = "#DDDDDD";

document
  .querySelector(".input-range--custom")
  .addEventListener("input", function () {
    var percent = (100 * (this.value - this.min)) / (this.max - this.min) + "%";
    //  this.setAttribute('value', this.value);
    //  this.setAttribute('title', this.value);
    this.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient( to right, ${fillColor}, ${fillColor} ${percent}, ${emptyColor} ${percent})`;
  });
```

```css
input[type="range"].input-range--custom {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 4px 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      to right,
      rgb(157, 60, 60),
      rgb(157, 60, 60) 48%,
      rgb(221, 221, 221) 48%
    );
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}

input[type="range"].input-range--custom:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="range"].input-range--custom::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="range"].input-range--custom:after {
  width: 20%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #9d3c3c;
}

input[type="range"].input-range--custom::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -5.5px;
  background: #9d3c3c;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <h5>Distance</h5>
  <div class="_flex-col range__container" style="width: 280px">
    <label for="distance"></label>
    <input id="distance" type="range" class="input-range--custom" min="0" max="50">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="range">
  <h5>Square</h5>
  <div class="_flex-col range__container" style="width: 280px">
    <label for="square"></label>
    <input id="square" type="range" class="input-range--custom" min="0" max="50">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="range">
  <h5>Min height</h5>
  <div class="_flex-col range__container" style="width: 280px">
    <label for="minheight"></label>
    <input id="minheight" type="range" class="input-range--custom" min="0" max="50">
  </div>

</div>

<div class="range">
  <h5>Max height</h5>
  <div class="_flex-col range__container" style="width: 280px">
    <label for="maxheight"></label>
    <input id="maxheight" type="range" class="input-range--custom" min="0" max="50">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are selecting only the first element with that class. Try querySelectorAll and then loop through them adding the event listener to each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `document.querySelector(".input-range--custom")`, you are selecting only the first `input` with the class `input-range--custom`.

So, the rest of the inputs do not have an event listener.

In order to select all of them, you need to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`.

Replace your JS code with following:

```js
var fillColor = "#9D3C3C",
  emptyColor = "#DDDDDD";

const rangeInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".input-range--custom")

rangeInputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("input", function () {
      var percent = (100 * (this.value - this.min)) / (this.max - this.min) + "%";
      //  this.setAttribute('value', this.value);
      //  this.setAttribute('title', this.value);
      this.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient( to right, ${fillColor}, 
      ${fillColor} ${percent}, ${emptyColor} ${percent})`;
  });
})
```